# call to a possibly undefined method loadmovie at the (Air for android) publisher

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'm creating an android app using `Flash CS5.5` and everything goes fine , but when I finished , I realized that the app size is VERY BIG coz of the lots pictures inside the app.

So, I uploaded the pics to a website and I created a square for the image and I give it an instance name (photo), putting this action to it

```
loadMovie("http://im37.gulfup.com/Jc0Ek.jpg", _root.photo.empty);
```

At the normal publish , the image shows perfectly with no errors 
but at the (AIR FOR Android) publish , it's giving me this error,

`(call to a possibly undefined method load movie)`

so , what is the action or the way that I should do , to make my android app size low or where to upload the images and how to link them to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `AS2` code and you need `AS3` like so:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://im37.gulfup.com/Jc0Ek.jpg");
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(urlRequest);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);

function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{    
    addChild(imageLoader); 
}

function onLoadError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("Error loading image");
}
```

Comment: that really works ,, thank you so much ...
I still have one problem !!
the pic does not show inside the (root) ,
I want the image to be shown inside a specific object !!
what to add inside the code?
and many thanks again

Comment: If object is `MovieClip` or `Sprite` then use, `object.addChild(imageLoader);`

Comment: I did as you said but it did not show at the middle of the object exactly.. sorry for too much asking Rajneeh ,,, but i'll be so glad ..

Comment: I mean:
the image position after i did object.addChild(imageLoader); changed next to the object , I want it to be inside the square exactly, *while the square is already MovieClip